# error: ..\..\..\opencv-2.4.8\modules\highgui\src\window.cpp:269: error: (-215) size.width>0 && size.height>0 in function cv::imshow

Tags: python, opencv

when i run this code taken from this links http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/py_tutorials/py_video/py_lucas_kanade/py_lucas_kanade.html  they give the following code the give the following Error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Python27\code\afan.py", line 48, in <module>
 cv2.imshow('frame',img)
error: ..\..\..\opencv-2.4.8\modules\highgui\src\window.cpp:269: error: (-215) size.width>0 && size.height>0 in function cv::imshow:
```

Comment: The link to the tutorial you followed is broken

Answer (score 1):

Write

```
cv2.line(mask, (a,b),(c,d), color[i].tolist(), 2)
cv2.circle(frame,(a,b),5,color[i].tolist(),-1)
```

instead

```
mask = cv2.line(mask, (a,b),(c,d), color[i].tolist(), 2)
frame = cv2.circle(frame,(a,b),5,color[i].tolist(),-1)
```

Answer (score 0):

This error says that your `img` doesn't have a correct size (in accordance to error `width` or `height` is 0).

Check your image size.

Comment: sir please visit this link when we set  a breakpoint in 44 and 45 they will run  simply not tracking                       http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/py_tutorials/py_video/py_lucas_kanade/py_lucas_kanade.html

Answer (score 0):

Images has zero size just after creation. Thus your `img` is created, but is not initialized with any actual content. Make sure that video files from tutorial are present and correctly loaded.

Comment: Maybe you don't have the appropriate codec installed in your system. Anyway, it is problem with frame acquisition, not with the image.